# Start Motion Layout automatically (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, splash-screen, android-motionlayout

I want to make an animated splashscreen and the Motion Layout should start automatically when you start the app. What can I do to make the Motion Layout start automatically?

Comment: I think you  should clarify us what is motion-scene actually? are you referring to motion layout?

Comment: Yes I mean a Motion Layout.

Answer (score 16):

Add the line autoTransition="animateToEnd" to your transition

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"

    motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"

    motion:duration="1000">
```

Comment: Great, it's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

First, assign an ID to MotionLayout in xml.

> then write below codes in your activity:

```
MotionLayout motionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motion_layout);     
motionLayout.transitionToEnd();
```

> if you want to reverse transition use this line of code:

```
motionLayout.transitionToStart();
```

Answer (score 0):

The motion:transitionFlags="disableIntraAutoTransition" will avoid the animations reanimating if the actual state is changed programmatically or by the user.

```
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
        motion:transitionFlags="disableIntraAutoTransition"
        motion:duration="1200">
    </Transition>
```